# Tablet and old Nexus don't appear in device manager

Tags: android-device-manager

I have three devices, a nexus 5 that I use daily and a Nexus 7 and 4. The last time I used Android Device Manager I could see all three. Now I looked but I can only see the N5. The other two (N7 and N5) don't show up. Tried both on the app on the N5 and in Chrome on the PC.

I want to see when my N7 was last seen because it bricked a while back (probably within the warranty period) and I just sent it in for repairs (outside warranty period). If I have a screenshot I can prove it broke within the warranty.

Does anyone here know how I can get the N7 to show up in Device Manager again? Or any other trick how I can prove  when it last worked?

Thanks GJ

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has a similar problem, I was able to see the last seen date for all my devices here:
https://play.google.com/settings